# Is there any alternative to XSLT

Tags: java, xml, xslt

In my application, we are converting a xml to java object using two steps. In 1st step we are doing XML to XML transformation using XSLT. In the second step, we are binding that XML to Java Object using JIBX API.

```
Step1:
DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse(inboundMessageData.getDataStream());
InputStream inStream = XsltTransformationUtil.transform(doc, xsltFileName);

Step2:
RuntimeDocument document = xmlBindingService.unmarshall(inStream, RuntimeDocument.class);
```

Is it possible that, these two steps can be achieved in single Step or do we have any API I can use for this. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Your Java model is fixed i presume? In that case you need the transformation step. This setup is very usual for messaging software, because it is very flexible.

Answer (score 0):

If your Java (domain) model does not align with the input document, i highly recommend to use XSLT as already done by you. However, it is possible to do this in one step and more efficient using standard java.
See [JAXBResult Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/util/JAXBResult.html).

Example code (Using Java SE 6+):

```
/**
 * Read file `./29238845.xml`, transform it to our internal canonical ProductXML and
 * bind to to a Java `Product` domain instance.
 */
@Test
public void testUnmarshal() throws TransformerException, JAXBException {
    final TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    final Transformer t = factory.newTransformer(
        new StreamSource(new File("./product.xsl")));
    final JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Product.class);
    final JAXBResult result = new JAXBResult(context);
    t.transform(new StreamSource(new File("./29238845.xml")), result);
    final Product p = (Product)result.getResult();
    assertEquals("N3V96EA", p.getMpn());
}
```